# Python regex in xml text, find tags

Tags: python, regex, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project using Python to search the XML of a research paper, searching for a particular string. I've accomplished this, but I need to get the search result's most previous section heading, which is the TITLE and LABEL tag and their content.

```
#<..... some XML .....>

<sec id="aj387295s3">
<label>3.</label>
<title><italic>CHANDRA</italic> OBSERVATIONS</title>
<p>The 13 candidates were observed with the Advanced CCD Imaging 
Spectrometer (ACIS; Burke et&nbsp;al. <xref ref-type="bibr" 
rid="aj387295r8">1997</xref>) on board <italic>Chandra</italic> 
(Weisskopf et&nbsp;al. <xref ref-type="bibr" 
rid="aj387295r46">1996</xref>). We chose the S3 chip to image the 
sources because of its better low-energy sensitivity. The standard 
TIMED readout with a frame time of 3.2 s was used, and the data were 
collected in VFAINT mode. In 12 cases, our <italic>Chandra</italic> 
observations led us to conclude that the RASS detection was not of a 
candidate INS (see Table&nbsp;<xref ref-type="table" 
rid="aj387295t1">1</xref>; the <xref ref-type="sec" 
rid="aj387295app1">Appendix</xref> includes a case-by-case discussion 
of these sources).</p>

#<..... more XML ....>
```

I have a regular expression to obtain the line that contains "Chandra", but I keep banging my head trying to get "3.CHANDRA OBSERVATIONS". It's probably super obvious but I don't have much training in regular expressions. My regular expression for Chandra and the rest of the line is "(.*)(c|C)handra\b"

Thank you! -Jenny

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse XML. Use `ElementTree` or `lxml`.

Comment: I'm primarily using BeautifulSoup because for some reason it's been cooperating better

Comment: A life lesson on [when not to use RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4743630). Use the modules recommended by Daniel or Jenny instead.

Comment: @Jenny: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EliasStrehle yes, the original post is me, Jenny

Comment: @Daniel I've been trying a bunch of different things, but my skills are low-level and I need a quick fix. I know regex isn't ideal, and I'm sure there are much better ways by parsing, but my idea is to just put <label> and <title> into the regex somehow so I can grab those tags that come before my Chandra search result, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you have found the correct `<sec>`-tag, you just need to get the text in the `<label>` and `<title>`.

```
title = '{} {}'.format(sec.findtext('label'), ''.join(sec.find('title').itertext())
```